# Left join filtering only works on where clause

Tags: t-sql

Can someone explain this to me?

I have two huge tables on which I wish to LEFT JOIN, but I think it would be more efficient to filter at the 'on' rather than the 'where'.

```
Select * from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Enabled = 1
```

Rather than

```
Select * from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id where t1.Enabled = 1
```

The above results are not the same. No matter what I put in as filtering, it stays unaffected:

```
Select * from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Enabled = 1
```

yields exactly the same results as

```
Select * from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Enabled = 0
```

Also, Table1 might only have a few records where Enabled = 1, so it would be inefficient to join millions of records first and then filter to find only 10.

I can do a sub select first, but I somehow I feel it is not the right way:

```
Select * from (Select * from Table1 where Enabled = 1) a left join Table2 t2 on a.Id = t2.Id
```

Comment: When the filter is inside the ON clause of a left join, it only filters the second table(its on the join condition) .. so when you put t1.enabled = 1 , when it will be 0 then it won't be filtered, only the left table data will be filtered because they are not answering the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Types of Joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx)

> Left outer join  **All** rows from the first-named table (the "left"
>   table, which appears leftmost in the JOIN clause) are included.
>   Unmatched rows in the right table do not appear.

When you move the condition to the where then t1.Enabled = 1 is applied

Do you have actual performance problems with the first query?

Comment: Yes, but maybe it is because my tables are very big, so I will have performance problems regardless. Is there a more efficient query that I can use?

Comment: Look at the query plan.